# Problem with data persisting when returning after navigating a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I am repeating the process of adding and completing the list on the detail screen.

The problem is that the previous list remains intact in the newly created detail fragment.

For example, if i made 3 lists in the previous detail screen, adding data in the new detail screen will add them to a list of size 3.

I've tried various things, but I still don't know what could be the cause.

---

**Fragment**

```
class WriteDetailFragment :  Fragment() {
    ...
    private val viewModel: WriteDetailViewModel by viewModels {
        WriteDetailViewModelFactory(
            (requireActivity().application as WorkoutApplication).writeDetailRepo
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWriteDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.apply {
            adapter = DetailAdapter()
            rv.adapter = adapter
            rv.itemAnimator = null

            // add set
            addSet.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.addSet()
            }
            // complete
            complete.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_writeDetailFragment_to_addRoutineFragment)
            }
        }
        
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.items.collect { list ->
                    adapter.submitList(list)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class WriteDetailViewModel(
    private val repository: WriteDetailRepository
    ): ViewModel() {

    private var _items: MutableStateFlow<List<WorkoutSetInfo>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())
    val items = _items.asStateFlow()

    fun addSet() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.add()
            _items.value = repository.getList()
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class WriteDetailRepository(val dao: WorkoutDao) {
    private var setInfoList = ArrayList<WorkoutSetInfo>()
    private lateinit var updatedList: List<WorkoutSetInfo>

    fun add() {
        val item = WorkoutSetInfo(set = setInfoList.size + 1)
        setInfoList.add(item)
        updatedList = setInfoList.toList()
    }
    fun getList() : List<WorkoutSetInfo> = updatedList
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason your repository isn't providing a `StateFlow` that each of your ViewModels can automatically get updates from?

Comment: Hmm... there's no particular reason...

Could this be the cause?